# Conflicting types compiling a LD_PRELOAD wrapper

Tags: c, linux, printf, ld-preload, conflicting-libraries

I tried to use LD_PRELOAD to hook `sprintf` function , so I will print to file the result of buffer:

```
#define _GNU_SOURCE
#include <stdio.h>
#include<dlfcn.h>

int sprintf (char * src , const char *  format , char* argp)
{
    int (*original_func)(char*,const char * , char*);
    original_func = dlsym(RTLD_NEXT,"sprintf");
    int ret = (*original_func)(src ,format,argp);
    FILE* output = fopen("log.txt","a");
    fprintf(output,"%s \n",src);
    fclose(output);
    return ret;


}
```

When I compile this code `gcc -Wall -fPIC -shared -o my_lib.so test_ld.c -ldl`

I got error

```
test_ld.c:5:5: error: conflicting types for ‘sprintf’
 int sprintf (char * src , const char *  format , char* argp)
     ^
In file included from test_ld.c:2:0:
/usr/include/stdio.h:364:12: note: previous declaration of ‘sprintf’ was here
 extern int sprintf (char *__restrict __s,
```

How can I fix that?

Comment: The error is because the types of your arguments to sprintf differ from the previously declared on (from the stdib). The type of sprintf is `int sprintf(char *restrict s, const char *restrict format, ...)`. I'm not sure if the `restrict` keywords are necessary, but `sprintf` takes a varargs as the third argument, not a pointer.

Answer (score 2):

Alex's first solution nicely addresses one problem: the conflicting declarations of `sprintf` (although there is no reason to *not* use the same signature as in `stdio.h`, see dbush's answer) . However, even then there remains one large elephant in the room: `sprintf` is a [variadic function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variadic_function).

That means that, whenever the wrapped program calls `sprintf` with anything other than one `char *` third argument, your output may not be correct (and may even depend on your compiler's `-O` level)

Calling variadic functions from variadic functions (what is essentially what you're doing here) is a [known problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51626390/how-to-wrap-variadic-functions-using-ld-preload). Any solution will be non-portable. With `gcc`, you can use `__buitlin_apply` and tap into `gcc`s own private way of handling argument lists:

```
/* sprintf.c, compile with gcc -Wall -fPIC -shared -o sprintf.so sprintf.c -ldl 
   and use with LD_PRELOAD=./sprintf.so <program> */

#define _GNU_SOURCE
#define sprintf xsprintf
#include <stdio.h>
#include<dlfcn.h>
#undef sprintf

# define ENOUGH 100 /* how many bytes of our call stack 
                       to pass to the original function */

int sprintf (char *src) /* only needs the first argument */                                                                                     
{                                                                                                                                                   
  void *original_func = dlsym(RTLD_NEXT,"sprintf");                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      
  void *arg = __builtin_apply_args();                                                                                                             
  void *ret = __builtin_apply((void *)original_func, arg, ENOUGH);                                                                                   
                                                                                                                                                
  FILE* output = fopen("log.txt","a");                                                                                                            
  fprintf(output,"%s \n",src);                                                                                                                    
  fclose(output);                                                                                                                                 
 __builtin_return(ret);                                                                                                                         
                                                                                                                                                
}
```

A few remarks:

- In well-designed libraries variadic functions will have a non-variadic counterpart that uses one `va_list` argument instead of a variable number of arguments. In that case (and `sprintf` - `vsprintf` is such a case) you can use Alex's (portable) second solution with the `va_*` macros. If not, the solution with `__builtin_apply()` is the only possible, albeit `gcc`-specific,  one.
- See also: [call printf using va_list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5977326/call-printf-using-va-list)
- Possibly depending on the compiler version, when compiling `main.c` with the `-O2` flag, `main()` will actually call `__sprintf_chk()` instead of `sprintf()` (regardless of `-fno-builtin`) and the wrapper *won't work*. To demonstrate the wrapper, compile `main.c` with `-O0`. Changing the main program to get the wrapper to work is the tail wagging the dog, of course. This shows the fragility of building wrappers: *programs often don't call the library functions you expect*. A `ltrace <program>` beforehand can save a lot of work....

Comment: 1) Why did you define # define ENOUGH 100 ? 2) you wrote int sprintf (char *src) with LD_PRELOAD don't you must write the full signature of function ? 3) Did you test your code? if I not include <stdio.h> for `FILE` I can't compile that code , and if I include stdio.h I get conflict error again.

Comment: `__builtin_apply()` returns a pointer to data describing how to perform a call with the same arguments as were passed to the current function. `__builtin_apply(func, arg, N)` calls `func` with the same arguments as the surrounding function `sprintf`.  For this it uses max `N` bytes of stack space - 100 bytes seems reasonable. As we don't need to refer to `format` and `argp` within our function, we can just leave them out - linkers don't typecheck.

Comment: Did you test your code? if I not include <stdio.h> for `FILE` I can't compile that code , and if I include stdio.h I get conflict error again.

Comment: Yes I did - the initial `#defines` and `#includes`  of the program are identical to Alex's solution - I added them

Comment: I took main.c from Alex and your code as `test_ld.c` and compile it with gcc `gcc -Wall -O2 -shared -fPIC -o libsprintf.so test_ld.c -ldl` and run this with `LD_PRELOAD=./libsprintf.so ./main` but this didn't work , txt file didn't create

Comment: I took main.c from Alex and your code as `test_ld.c` and compile it with gcc `gcc -Wall -O2 -shared -fPIC -o libsprintf.so test_ld.c -ldl` and run this with `LD_PRELOAD=./libsprintf.so ./main` but this didn't work , txt file didn't create

Comment: Yes, even if compiled with `-fno-builtin` `main` will not call your new and shiny `sprintf`. I solved it by replacing  `#include <stdio.h>` by `extern int sprintf(char*, char *, ...); extern void puts(char *);`. This is an implementation thing (`sprintf` may be a macro inside `stdio.h` for all I know) and is not very relevant for the general problem.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/230770/discussion-between-microsoctcprog-and-hans-lub).

Comment: Please edit you post with full solution that I can compile and run

Answer (score 2):

The main problem you're having is that your prototype for `sprintf` doesn't match the official one.  Your function has this signature:

```
int sprintf (char * src , const char *  format , char* argp);
```

While the official one has:

```
int sprintf(char *str, const char *format, ...);
```

You'll need to change your function to have this signature.  Once you do that, you'll need to use a `va_list` to get the variadic argument.  Then you would use that to call `vsprintf` which takes an argument of this type instead of using `dlsym` to load `sprintf`.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdarg.h>

int sprintf (char * src , const char *  format , ...)
{
    va_list args;
    va_start(args, format);
    int ret = vsprintf(src, format, args);
    va_end(args);

    FILE* output = fopen("log.txt","a");
    fprintf(output,"%s \n",src);
    fclose(output);
    return ret;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can rename the symbol in stdio, but then there's another problem, compilers like gcc use built-in implementations, unless you pass a flag like [`-fno-builtin`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54281841/2498790), the compiler will generate the code inline in the executable, it won't link any library for functions like sprintf.

sprintf.c:

```
#define _GNU_SOURCE
#define sprintf xsprintf
#include <stdio.h>
#include<dlfcn.h>
#undef sprintf

int sprintf (char * src , const char *  format , char* argp)
{
    int (*original_func)(char*,const char * , char*);
    original_func = dlsym(RTLD_NEXT,"sprintf");
    int ret = (*original_func)(src ,format,argp);
    FILE* output = fopen("log.txt","a");
    fprintf(output,"%s \n",src);
    fclose(output);
    return ret;
}
```

main.c:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    char buffer[80];
    sprintf(buffer, "hello world");
    puts(buffer);
    return 0;
}
```

Makefile:

```
all: libsprintf.so main

main: main.c
    gcc -Wall -O2 -fno-builtin -o main main.c

libsprintf.so: sprintf.c
    gcc -Wall -O2 -shared -fPIC -fno-builtin -o libsprintf.so sprintf.c -ldl

.PHONY: clean
clean:
    -rm -f main libsprintf.so
```

usage:

```
make
LD_PRELOAD=./libsprintf.so ./main
```

*edit*

sprintf.c with variadic implementation (it doesn't call sprintf):

```
#define _GNU_SOURCE
#define sprintf xsprintf
#include <stdio.h>
#include<dlfcn.h>
#undef sprintf
#include <stdarg.h>

int sprintf (char * src , const char *  fmt , ...)
{
    va_list args;
    va_start(args, fmt);
    int ret = vsprintf(src, fmt, args);
    va_end(args);

    FILE* output = fopen("log.txt","a");
    fprintf(output,"%s \n", src);
    fclose(output);
    return ret;
}
```

Comment: 1) Why does `main.c` must be compile with `-fno-builtin` 2) `#define sprintf xsprintf` replace `sprintf ` into `stdio.h` ?

Comment: @MicrosoctCprog 1) see the link in the updated answer, there's a mention of gcc documentation about no-builtin. 2) yes, once you define *something* as *somethingelse* everything matching *something* in the sources (including included headers) is replaced by the preprocessor with *somethingelse*

Comment: I sorry that I didn't mention that but I can't compile main.c with `-fno-builtin` my assumption that I can't control of hook binary, only run it

Comment: @MicrosoctCprog even if you didn't mention I assumed so, the problem is, if your executable was built using built-in, won't link any library, sprintf won't be defined as dynamic symbol and you can't use LD_PRELOAD to hook it.